# Empty Horizontal Table Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've been following (and converting to swift) a Ray Wenderlich tutorial ([link to tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2)) on how to make an interface with horizontal tables. My application loads but does not show any data in the cells as below:

[image: iOS simulator]

I have three swift files in the project:
`ArticleTableViewCell.swift`
`HorizontalTableViewCell.swift`
`ArticleListViewController.swift`

```
// ArticleTableViewCell.swift
// HorizontalTables

import UIKit

class ArticleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var thumbnail: UIImageView!
    var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        var frameA: CGRect = CGRectMake(3, 3, 100, 314)
        thumbnail = UIImageView(frame: frameA)
        thumbnail.opaque = true
        self.contentView.addSubview(thumbnail)

        var frameB: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, thumbnail.frame.size.height * 0.632, thumbnail.frame.size.width, thumbnail.frame.size.height * 0.37)
        titleLabel = UILabel(frame: frameB)
        titleLabel.opaque = true
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 12)
        thumbnail.addSubview(titleLabel)

        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI) * 0.5)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func reuseIdentifier() -> String {
        return "ArticleCell"
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

```
// HorizontalTableViewCell.swift
// HorizontalTables

import UIKit

class HorizontalTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var horizontalTableView: UITableView!
    var articles: NSArray!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        var frameA: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 106, 320)
        horizontalTableView = UITableView(frame: frameA)
        horizontalTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator =  false
        horizontalTableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        horizontalTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI) * 0.5)
        horizontalTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 106)
        horizontalTableView.rowHeight = 106
        horizontalTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
        horizontalTableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        horizontalTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 201/252, green: 235/252, blue: 245/252, alpha: 1)
        horizontalTableView.dataSource = self
        horizontalTableView.delegate = self
        self.addSubview(horizontalTableView)  
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return articles.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ArticleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ArticleTableViewCell

        let currentArticle: NSDictionary = articles.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSDictionary

        cell.titleLabel.text = currentArticle.objectForKey("Title") as NSString
        var pics: AnyObject = currentArticle.objectForKey("ImageName")!
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "\(pics)")

        return cell
    }
}
```

```
// ArticleListViewController.swift
// HorizontalTables

import UIKit

class ArticleListViewController: UITableViewController {
    var articleDictionary: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()

    let kHeadlineSectionHeight: Int = 26
    let kRegularSectionHeight: Int = 26

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.rowHeight = 45

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Articles", ofType: "plist")

        UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 201/252, green: 235/252, blue: 245/252, alpha: 1)

        articleDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)!
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 201/252, green: 235/252, blue: 245/252, alpha: 1)
        tableView.rowHeight = 106

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 45
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return articleDictionary.allKeys.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1  
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let keys: NSArray = articleDictionary.allKeys
        var sortedCategories: NSArray = keys.sortedArrayUsingSelector("localizedCompare:")

        var categoryName: NSString = sortedCategories.objectAtIndex(section) as NSString

        return categoryName.substringFromIndex(1)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as HorizontalTableViewCell

        let keys: NSArray = articleDictionary.allKeys

        var sortedCategories: NSArray = keys.sortedArrayUsingSelector("localizedCompare:")

        var categoryName: NSString = sortedCategories.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as NSString

        let currentCategory: NSArray = articleDictionary.objectForKey(categoryName) as NSArray

        cell.articles = currentCategory

        if (indexPath.row % 2) == 1 {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 201/252, green: 235/252, blue: 245/252, alpha: 1)  
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on why I have tableView cells with no data?

Comment: You are trying the show a horizontal tableView on each row of the ArticlesTable?

Comment: Try calling reloadData in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't register your cells to your tableview. If you're using a Storyboard, you need to enter in the cell identifier there. If XIBs, you'll need to register the class to the tableview first:

`tableView.registerClass(ArticleTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ArticleCell")`

Answer (score 0):

The `UITableViewController` will be initialized. In the meanwhile, the delegate method and data sources methods are called for initializing purpose. That moment, you will only get what you have from your prototype of `UITableViewCell`. So, you have to call `reloadData` after you successfully distribute the data.

Comment: just use Custom Cell without using UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. It doesn't even use `HorizontalTableViewCell(frame:CGRect)` to init a TableViewCell, unless you manually do so. You should do something like this:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? HorizontalTableViewCell

if cell == nil {
    cell = HorizontalTableViewCell(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height))
}
```

Same for ArticleTableViewCell:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ArticleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? ArticleTableViewCell
if cell == nil {
    cell = ArticleTableViewCell(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 106, 106))
}
```

Comment: Thats incorrect, calling tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(:forIndexPath:) will always return a cell if its registered with the tableview. You might be confused with the original method tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(:) that will return nil if the cell is not in the reuse pool

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this init function in your cell

```
initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
```